# Optional java пытаюсь получить объект

Tags: java, optional

есть метод который возвращает оптионал я указываю

```
 public <R> Optional<R> db(String sql, List<Object> param, FunEx<PreparedStatement, R> fun) {
        Optional rsl = Optional.empty();
        try (var conn = source.getConnection();
             var pr = conn.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) {
            this.forIdex(param, (index, value) -> dispat.get(value.getClass()).accept(index + 1, pr, value));

            rsl.of(fun.apply(pr));
            System.out.println(fun.apply(pr));
            System.out.println(rsl.get());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return rsl;
    }
```

и так у нас в методе есть функциональный метод который вернёт нам что-то  к примеру объект юзер fun.apply(pr)
также я пробую ниже вывести в консоль этого юзера System.out.println(fun.apply(pr));
и в консоль я нормально вывожу
Users{id=59 createDate=2018-12-26T23:37:21.315052, name=sacha , login=alexmur07}
но почему я не могу добавить объект пользователя в оптионал? 
            rsl.of(fun.apply(pr)); - в это строчку я его добавляю и вот в этой строчке `System.out.println(rsl.get());` я получаю
`java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present` будто элемент не был добавлен в оптионал да как так то????

```
public Users findById(Users users) {
        return this.db(
                "select * from users where id = ?", Arrays.asList(Integer.valueOf(users.getId())),
                ps -> {
                    Users res = null;
                    try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
                        if (rs.next()) {
                            res = new Users(String.valueOf(rs.getInt("id")), rs.getString("name"),
                                    rs.getString("login"), rs.getTimestamp("create_date").toLocalDateTime());
                        }
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                    }
                    return res;
                }
        ).orElse(new Users());

    }
```

Comment: rsl = Optional.of(fun.apply(pr));

Comment: public Users findById(Users users) {
        return this.db(
                "select * from users where id = ?", Arrays.asList(Integer.valueOf(users.getId())),
                ps -> {
                    Users res = new Users("`name", "login");
                    return res;
                }
        ).orElse(new Users());

    }

Comment: т.е. db  это функционалка которой я пользуюсь и она у меня возвращает объект опитионал в который прилетает объект скажем юзерс и если этот объект равен нулл то метод просто создаст объект юзерс с полями нуллл но дело в том что он всегда видет что приходит объект нулл хотя вывод в консоль говорит обратное

Comment: rsl = Optional.of(fun.apply(pr));  да блииин да как так то  вот как я тупанул то ну на пустом месте

Answer (score 0):

`rsl.of(fun.apply(pr));` на самом деле транслируется в `Optional.of(fun.apply(pr));`

Этот метод создает новый инстанс `Optional`.

Исправьте на

```
rsl = Optional.of(fun.apply(pr));
```

и будет вам счастье.